# Using Selenium C# to click a recent link on a web page that updates

Tags: c#, selenium

[image: This is the website I am trying to click links on]

So, i am trying to use Selenium to scrape this webpage that updates every couple seconds. I am looking to click on the most recent link which, in this case, is the link by Edward Researcher. This list will update multiple times and get updated with new links stacking at the top.

My current code basically takes the top most link of the entire page [image: Like getting hits from the closed new hits tab here] when I want it to take links that are shown on the page starting from the top

```
  allLinks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]//a")).ToHashSet();
```

This will get all the clickable links going top down using a tags to grab the links. My problem is trying to only get links from one place on the webpage and grab that link everytime it updates. Not really sure how to do that since the code and xPath changes with every added link. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: HTML CODE:]

The bottom most mark in red is the current link that I inspected that is topmost but when the page gets updated with new Links the two top red marks are where they will be updated in another DIV.

The Code that I have a t the moment works to grab the first link on the page but I would prefer to start at the Logged hits section as shown in the first image. Here is the code that makes it work:

```
 public static void searchAllLinks()
    {
        //HitForker is labelled as '0'
        //PandaCrazy tab is labellled as '1'
        //Start index at 1
        int listIndex = 1;

        //Different numbers need for the first run down the list 
        bool firstRun = true;

        //HashSet to store all IWebElements found on page at runtime 
        HashSet<IWebElement> allLinks;

        //Get browser tabs open at current time 
        var browserTabs = driver.WindowHandles;

        //Switch to HF
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);

        //Grab links from page starting at Logged Hits Most recent Div
        allLinks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]//a")).ToHashSet();

        //Loop through all links in hash
        //Hashset contains every link on the page. Only need the middle link to access the content 
        foreach(IWebElement value in allLinks)
        {
            if(firstRun == true)
            {
                //Second link in the hash
                if(listIndex == 2)
                {
                    value.Click();
                    firstRun = false;
                    listIndex = 0;
                    whatToClick(value);
                }
            }
            //When linkIndex is 5 then click the value and reset to 0
            if(listIndex == 5)
            {
                value.Click();
                whatToClick(value);
                listIndex = 0;
            }

            listIndex++;

        }

    }
    //Method to find which webpage opened on successfull click 
    public static void whatToClick(IWebElement currentLink)
    {
        //Grabs the browser handles open
        var browserTabs = driver.WindowHandles;

        //When the link is clicked on switch to that tab
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[2]);

        //2 options
            //Hit is not available then add to PC
            //Hit is available then accept 
        try
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/p/span/span/button[2]")).Displayed == true)
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/p/span/span/button[2]")).Click();
                driver.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                driver.Close();
                driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);
            }

            //Switch Back to the HF
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);

        //Catch exception to catch if the hit cannot be accepted
        } catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException e )
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/span/span/button")).Displayed == true)
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/span/span/button")).Click();
                driver.Close();

            }

            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);
        }
        catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException w)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Window Not open");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML, code trials and errors (if any)?

Comment: Presumably each time a new link gets added, it gets added as the first *index* of the list. You should just be able to access `div[0]` or similar. Having said that, we'd need the HTML to be able to give a more accurate selector.

Comment: @DebanjanB The post Has been updated

Comment: @ObsidianAge Post has been updated with revelant HTML

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. The SSL certificate for the site hosting the image has problems with it right now (as imgur.com frequently does) so we cannot see your code.

Answer (score -1):

Please click the element using relative xpath as follows

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='log_table']/div[0]/div/div[1]/span[1]//a")).Click()
```

The above xpath will focus on the first  of the table and accesses the hyperlink of that.